# Сравнение двух файлов на Bash

Tags: linux, bash

Задача сравнить два файла на Bash.
/path/to/file/ip.txt и 
/path/to/file/ip-stanby.txt
Если они равны, то вывести на экран "Равны" и аналогично.

Заранее Спасибо.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
#!/bin/sh
if cmp -s файл-1 файл-2 ; then
 echo Равны
fi
```

Или, для любителей компактного кода:

```
#!/bin/sh
cmp -s файл-1 файл-2 && echo Равны
```

Answer (score 2):

просто для информации.

можно сравнить, например, md5-суммы файлов (да, это будет чуть затратнее, нежели вызов программы *cmp*).

`file1` и `file2` — идентичны, а `file3` отличается от них:

```
$ cat file1 | md5sum -c --status <(cat file2 | md5sum) && echo равны || echo нет
равны
$ cat file1 | md5sum -c --status <(cat file3 | md5sum) && echo равны || echo нет
нет
```

Answer (score 0):

Команда `diff` в помощь

```
diff file1 file2
```

[Документация opennet](https://www.opennet.ru/docs/RUS/diff/diff-3.html)