# В Bash получить строки совпадающие по содержимому в двух файлах

Tags: bash

Нужно получить все совпадения строк из двух файлов в третий файл. Номер строк не важен. Если это важно, то совпадение будет только одно

Comment: Связанный: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/504023/262779

Comment: `diff` - сравнивать файлы построчно,
`cmp` - сравнить два файла побайтно